# CSSRules group selectors with common properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

This script when included in an HTML document which includes any declared styles (excluding those set by `style=""`) will output an optimized stylesheet to the to the page. The script uses the following methods...

1. Ignore any `@` or `:` rules to leave responsive styles as is.
2. Separate the rules into single selector rules so we can test for inheritance later on.
3. Remove rules that apply to selectors which don't exist in the document, thanks to [@RickHitchcock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903374/rick-hitchcock) for this.
4. Retrieve both the declared and computed styles in the same format (excluding percentages) then compare both values each other, then remove the property and check again.
5. if the declared value matches the computed value and by removing the property the value changes, then set the keep flag. This tells us whether the property has an effect on an element, if no elements were affected by the property... remove it.
6. If there are no properties in the remaining `CSSRule` then remove that rule.
7. As a side effect most selectors which don't change the browsers default setting will be removed (unless using `font` as opposed to `font-*` and similar which will activate the rest of the settings for that property).

While running this script on a site which includes styles relating to dynamic elements, I just wrap them in a media query

```
@media (min-width: 0px) {
    /* This says that these styles always apply */
}
```

#### Question

How can I group the selectors with common properties?

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/w27ze0hr/15/))

```js
var stylesheets = document.styleSheets, stylesheet, i;
var ruleText = "";
if(stylesheets && stylesheets.length) {
    for (i = 0; (stylesheet = stylesheets[i]); i++) {
        var rules = stylesheet.rules, rule, j;
        if(rules && rules.length) {
            for (j = 0; (rule = rules[j]); j++) {
                if(rule.type === rule.STYLE_RULE) {
                    if(rule.selectorText.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
                        var newRules = [];
                        var selectors = rule.selectorText.split(','), selector, k;
                        for(k = 0; (selector = selectors[k]); k++) {
                            var styles = rule.style, style, l;
                            var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector.trim()), element, l;
                            if(elements.length) {
                                var styleString = '';
                                for(m = 0; (style = styles[m]); m++) {
                                    styleString += style + ': ' + styles.getPropertyValue(style) + "; ";
                                }
                                newRules.push((selector.trim() + ' { ' + styleString.trim() + ' }'));
                            }
                        }
                        stylesheet.deleteRule(j);
                        for(k = 0; (rule = newRules[k]); k++) {
                            stylesheet.insertRule(rule, j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (j = 0; (rule = rules[j]); j++) {
                if(rule.type === rule.STYLE_RULE && rule.selectorText.indexOf(':') < 0) {
                    var styles = rule.style, style, k;
                    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(rule.selectorText);
                    if(elements && elements.length) {
                        for(k = 0; (style = styles[k]); k++) {
                            var value = styles.getPropertyValue(style);
                            if(value.indexOf('%') < 0) {
                                var elements = document.querySelectorAll(rule.selectorText), element, m;
                                var keep = false;
                                for(m = 0; (element = elements[m]); m++) {
                                    var computed = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(style);
                                    var match1 = value === computed;
                                    styles.removeProperty(style);
                                    var computed = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(style);
                                    var match2 = value === computed;
                                    styles.setProperty(style, value);
                                    if( match1 && !match2 ) {
                                        keep = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(!keep) {
                                    styles.removeProperty(style);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ruleText += rule.cssText + "\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    ruleText += rule.cssText + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + ruleText + '<pre>';
```

Future viewers: this is available on github as [optiCSS](https://github.com/humbleRumble/optiCSS) (read: eye-pleasing)

Comment: https://github.com/giakki/uncss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks great, and I have only a minor suggestion.

Change your code as follows:

```
for (j = 0; rule = rules[j]; j++) {
  var styles = rule.style, style, k;
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(rule.selectorText);

  if(elements.length) {
    for(k = 0; style = styles[k]; k++) {
      ...
    }
    console.log(rule.cssText);
  }
}
```

This will prevent the output of rules that don't have any matching HTML.

In **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyo6m3x1/)**, the `li` rule is output with your code, but it's not output with the above modification.

The next challenge is to simplify those `font`, `border`, `padding`, … styles.

---

Based on your **Edit #25**, you're left with a string that looks like this:

```
html { margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; height: 100%; }
body { margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; height: 100%; margin-top: 0px; }
body { margin-bottom: 5px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); }
@media (max-width: 500px) { 
  body { background: blue; }
}
```

Here's how to turn it into this:

```
html {margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;height:100%;}
body {margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;height:100%;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:5px;background-color:rgb(255 0 0);}
@media (max-width: 500px) { 
  body { background: blue; }
}
```

In the process, you'll get two objects:

```
html {"margin-right":"0px;","margin-left":"0px;","height":"100%;"}
body {"margin-right":"0px;","margin-left":"0px;","height":"100%;","margin-top":"0px;","margin-bottom":"5px;","background-color":"rgb(255, 0, 0);"}
```

First, keep your media query output separate since you don't want it to be affected:

```
var ruleText = "", mediaText = "";
...
        if (styles.length) {
            ruleText += rule.cssText + "\n";
        }
    } else {
        mediaText += rule.cssText + "\n";
    }
```

Then place this after your loop:

```
var inp= ruleText.split('\n'),
    out= '',
    selectors= {};

inp.forEach(function(val) {
  if(val) {
    var selector= val.split(/ *{/)[0],
        styles= val.split(/{ */)[1].split('}')[0].split(/; */);

    selectors[selector]= selectors[selector] || {};
    styles.forEach(function(val) {
      if(val) {
        var st= val.split(/ *: */);
        selectors[selector][st[0]]= st[1]+';';
      }
    });
  }
});

for(var i in selectors) {
  out+= i+' '+JSON.stringify(selectors[i]).replace(/[,"]/g,'')+'\n';
}
document.body.innerHTML= '<pre>'+out+mediaText+'</pre>';
```

For simplicity, the code above assumes there is no string content in the CSS that contains double quotes, semicolons, commas, or curly braces.  That would complicate things somewhat.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c249wbxL/)

Comment: Be thankful you have CSS files to clean up.  I've spent plenty of time cleaning old Word-to-HTML and Dreamweaver files, which were full of inline CSS.